# Resize popup.html in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have this chrome extension that shows some content in the popup.html. As the content changes at "run-time" the popup.html sizes change too, expanding where there's more content to show. The problem that I have is that the popup.html don't resize itself back according to a smaller content. How can I do that?

Comment: if necessary i can post some screenshots to explain better

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the very beginning of the popup.html - it looks like you've forgotten to add it

Comment: I wouldn't have ever thought that could be the reason. Thanks

Comment: This was extremely useful for me, since I had the same problem. Could you explain why this actually helps? Thanks.

Comment: This was the top resutls on my google search so i might add

https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype

Although it doesn't explain directly the "resizing problem" in question it is worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

I had a pesky CSS line:

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

in my popup's CSS and removing it made the popup auto-resize itself again.