# How to resize chrome extension window in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to resize my chrome extensions window but I do not know how to do it.

```js
document.write('<div class="card" id="main-card" style="width: 18rem; height: 20rem;">')
document.write('<img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">')
document.write('<div class="card-body">')
document.write('<h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>')
document.write('<p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card\'s content.</p>')
document.write('<button id="test" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</button>')
document.write('</div>')
document.write('</div>  ')


document.getElementById("test").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("main-card").style.height = "10rem"
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

manifest.json
{
"name": "Test",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "This extension",
"author": "Test",
"browser_action": {
"default_popup": "index.html",
"default_title": "WRB"
},
"manifest_version": 2
}

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean a popup window in your extension?

Comment: I mean the default popup window that opens when you click the icon.

Comment: I believe the window will automatically resize to fit your content so if you need to change the size of the popup window you just change the size of your content.

Comment: When I change the size of my bootstrap card to a number like 20rem and then my bootstrap card becomes 10rem it does not change the height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resize the popup window you just need to resize your content. The best way to do that is by editing the width and/or height of your `<body>` element.

For example:

```
document.body.style.width = '600px';
```

If that isn't working make sure you have a DOCTYPE declaration [as per this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498685/resize-popup-html-in-chrome-extension)

**EDIT:**

Now that I see the code you are using here is an updated solution.

```js
document.body.innerHTML += 
`<div class="card" id="main-card" style="width: 18rem; height: 20rem;"><img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card\'s content.</p>
        <button id="test" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</button>
    </div>
</div>`;


document.getElementById("test").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("main-card").style.height = "10rem";
    document.documentElement.style.height = "10rem";
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

It looks like the problem you were having is that the `documentElement` (Your `<html>` tag) was never resizing when the rest of the content shrunk. I just added `document.documentElement.style.height = "10rem";` to the callback function to also decrease the size of the document.

In addition but not related to this specific issue, I would not recommend using `document.write()` because it will cause you problems later down the line especially with [overwriting your original page content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write). To fix this I appended your HTML tags to the `innerHTML` of your document's `<body>`. I also moved the `<script>` tag for your popup script to the body so that it runs only after the body has been loaded.

**How to Find A Problematic Element**

Since you mentioned that while this works on the sample code, it does not in your actual code here is how you can go about finding the problematic element(s) in your actual project.

1. Open your popup window.
2. Right click within the window and click inspect.
3. This will bring up dev tools.
4. Hover over your elements in the elements panel, they will be highlighted.
5. Look for an element that is taking up more space than your desired height. It is best to start from the outermost element and work your way in.
6. Once you identify an element that is causing an issue, try changing the size of that element on the click of the button to test if the window resizes with it.
7. If it works, good news, you found your problem. If it doesn't, repeat steps 4-6 with the next outermost element until you find the element that is causing problems.

Here is a GIF showcasing how to open and view elements in dev tools:

[image]

Comment: In my extension it changes the size of the body to 20rem and when you click a button it changes the bootstrap card in it to 10rem but even doing this it does not change the body to 10rem instead the card is 10rem and the body is 20rem.

Comment: Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you ever reset the body to 10rem when you change the dimensions of the card. Therefore, even after your card has shrunk to 10rem, your body is still set to 20rem.

Comment: How can I reset the body to 10rem? I have already tried your solution but it is not working.

Comment: I originally missed quotes around the size. I tested on my own and it is now working. I have updated the answer to reflect the change.

Comment: I did my test with quotes and it is not resizing.

Comment: This is the code I used:  document.body.style.height = "13rem";

Comment: The card automatically increases the size of the window when the card size increases but when it gets smaller the window is not getting smaller. Is there a way to refresh the styling of the body to automatically adjust based on the height of the bootstrap card?

Comment: I just tested again and editing an element in the body that would make it larger than it could contain expands and retracts the popup window as you would expect. Can you share some more code so I get a better idea of what you are doing?

Comment: This is not my exact application but it is a example of the problem.

Comment: I have edited my solution now that I see your sample code. I believe it should now be working.

Comment: This works on the example but it is not working on the application I am creating. Is there a way to refresh the default styling? Could you put down a couple more ways as well.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include instructions on how to find the element that is causing you problems.

Answer (score 0):

For the given requirement, the HTML *min-width* property can be set to a minimum fixed size, and the height can be set to *fit-content* as given below.

**CSS:**

```
html { 
    min-width: 400px;
    height: fit-content;
}
```